# Creating label using ZPL Python

Tags: python, python-requests, shutil, zpl

I am trying to create a label with QR code and with some text and save the label as PDF. I am unable to alter the size of the label to 9 X 3 cms. How do I do that?

What I tried so far?

```
import requests
import shutil

zpl = """
^XA
^FO50,60^A0,15^FDID 123456^FS

^FO100,100
^BQN,2,5
^FDQA,QR_CODE^FS

^FO120,270^A0,15^FDTest here^FS
^FO150,290^A0,15^FDSome more text here^FS
^FO25,25^GB500,350,2^FS

^XZ
"""

# adjust print density (8dpmm), label width (4 inches), label height (6 inches), and label index (0) as necessary
url = 'http://api.labelary.com/v1/printers/8dpmm/labels/3.5x10/0/'
files = {'file' : zpl}
headers = {'Accept' : 'application/pdf'} # omit this line to get PNG images back
response = requests.post(url, headers = headers, files = files, stream = True)

if response.status_code == 200:
    response.raw.decode_content = True
    with open('label.pdf', 'wb') as out_file: # change file name for PNG images
        shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
else:
    print('Error: ' + response.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the right combination of basically 4 parameters, which are:

1. *The size of your graphical elements in dots, for example the texts and the bounding box.*
2. *The density (or resolution) of your label, which should match your printer's.*
3. *The size of the (physical) label.*
4. *The size of the PDF page.*

Here's an example of how to control each one of these.
Only the relevant lines are shown:

```
# The values in your ZPL set the sizes in dots:
zpl = """
^XA
^FO50,60^A0,15^FDID 123456^FS

... (your full ZPL here) ...

"""

# Then:

# 1. Set the density (24dpmm) and the size of the label in inches (2.8x2):
url = 'http://api.labelary.com/v1/printers/24dpmm/labels/2.8x2/0/'

# 2. Set the PDF page size, here A4:
headers = {'Accept' : 'application/pdf', 'X-Page-Size':'A4'}
```

Note: if the PDF page size is not set in the header, then it will match the physical label size.